# AAC bitstream not in ADTS format and extradata missing

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming

With FFMPEG, I'm sending a stream from Computer A over to Computer B, via UDP.
This is done over a MPEGTS stream, encoded with libx264 and aac.
Computer B takes this stream with FFMPEG and puts it into an m3u8 playlist.

After a random time (2-35 minutes), the message

```
[mpegts @ 0533f000] AAC bitstream not in ADTS format and extradata missing
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input
```

appears. 
What I figures is that the receiving FFMPEG can't read the header file of the audio part for this particular package, and since it can't put video and audio together anymore, it stops creating the .ts files and just stops running.

Here's the cmdline of the receiving stream:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://address -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -analyzeduration 100000 -probesize 100000-segment_list_flags +live-cache -segment_time 8 -segment_wrap 10 out%03d.ts
```

Now I need to know the answer to either one of these 2 questions:

1) Can I put something in my commandline in order to avoid this particular problem or

2) Can I tell FFMPEG to just ignore it for this particular message, quite possibly creating weird audio or none at all, and to simply move on to the next one?

Comment: sounds like data loss [lost udp packets].  Possibly receive using tcp instead? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming (you could re-ask question 2 on the ffmpeg ML)

Comment: Yes you're right, it's the packet loss. I've switched to HLS for now, but I'm still interested in how to circumvent this issue. (:

Comment: are you receiving using ffmpeg? is it a zeranoe build [windows]?

Comment: I've streamed this from Linux/Debian with a self-compiled FFMPEG to a Windows Server 2012 with the Zeranoe build FFMPEG.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, any luck in resolving this issue?

Comment: Sadly, no. I switched to HTTP Live Streaming using playlists written to the hard drive, and that one doesn't have this problem.